# When does SQLite RANDOM() generate values?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm attempting to generate a set of random numbers in SQLite using `RANDOM()` and then do some operations on the random variable. However, I noticed that the random numbers are perhaps too random.

If I generate a random number `foo` and then do an operations such as `foo + 1` the random numbers that comprise `foo` differ between the two steps.

As an example:

```
create table example (row);
insert into example values ((1), (2), (3), (4), (5));
select rand_int, rand_int from (select random() as rand_int from example);
```

I would expect the values of two columns to be the same as they are both `rand_int`. However, I get the following:

```
rand_int            |rand_int
-5260381568243288466|-7496653829633048866
-8052390701785370463| 7419520968895340417
-4115751602452871973| 1327613517212963758
 -349032467862864821| 8300157345288949689
-7986362792467963959|-5529549013375197694
```

Does SQLite store randomly drawn values for `rand_int` when running the sub-query which are then fixed outside of the sub-query (which is the behavior I expected) or does SQLite randomly generate data for `rand_int` each time the variable is required (which is the behavior I think I am seeing)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite generates exactly one random number each time `random()` is called.

However, the query optimizer will rearrange terms in the query, so what you wrote is not necessarily the same what actually gets executed.

You could [exploit some SQLite internals to disable subquery flattening](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#flattening):

```
select r, r from (select random() as r from example limit -1) limit -1;
```

Or, more obvious, store the random numbers in a temporary table before doing computations on them.

Comment: It had never occurred to me or the people I asked around the office that the optimizer might be to blame.